# PyQt5 QTimer count until specific seconds

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtimer

I am creating a program in python and i am using pyqt. I am currently working with the QTimer and i want to print "timer works" every seconds and stop printing after 5 seconds. Here is my code:

```
timers = []
def thread_func():
    print("Thread works")
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(timer_func)
    timer.start(1000)
    print(timer.remainingTime())
    print(timer.isActive())
    timers.append(timer)

def timer_func():
    print("Timer works")
```

Comment: The `QTimer` class doesn't support stopping after a fixed number of timeouts. You will have to keep a count and stop it explicitly.

Comment: Can you please do a demo for me? I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is a simple demo showing how to create a timer that stops after a fixed number of timeouts.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

def start_timer(slot, count=1, interval=1000):
    counter = 0
    def handler():
        nonlocal counter
        counter += 1
        slot(counter)
        if counter >= count:
            timer.stop()
            timer.deleteLater()
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(handler)
    timer.start(interval)

def timer_func(count):
    print('Timer:', count)
    if count >= 5:
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()

app = QtCore.QCoreApplication([])
start_timer(timer_func, 5)
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Woah! It is what i've been lookin' for. Thanks here pal!