# Qtimer and closing out an applicaiton after 15 seconds have passed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtimer

Evening. I am having a bit of a hard time both understanding QTimer and how it works as well as getting the below code to work. As much as I hate copy/pasting, I just cannot figure it out. The goal of this is to run the program for 15 seconds and then exit out completely. Everything else works, but when I try to integrate QTimer to count how many seconds have passed, it does nothing or just simply does not work regardless of the variations I try. Below is the latest code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
import winsound
import time 
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(321, 249)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 320, 248))
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)              
        self.label.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.label.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        #Plays the movie in the Label
        movie = QMovie("giphy.gif")        
        self.label.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()

        #Plays the sound with the movie
        winsound.PlaySound("magicwrd.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC|winsound.SND_LOOP)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


    #Borrowed and modified from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656634/pyqt5-qtimer-count-until-specific-seconds
    #Goal is to run the application for 15 seconds and then exit out completely. 
    def start_timer(self, slot, count=1, interval=1000):
        counter = 0
        def handler():
            nonlocal counter
            counter += 1
            slot(counter)
            if counter >= count:
                timer.stop()
                timer.deleteLater()
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(handler)
        timer.start(interval)

    def timer_func(self, count):
        if count >= 5:
            sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    Ui_MainWindow.start_timer(Ui_MainWindow.timer_func, 5)
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: slot(counter) is causing it to exit. try commenting that out. as an ultimate solution, you should try async with ThreadEventLoop (quamash) to achieve your gif player application

Comment: That code is not an excess, it is the [MRE].

Answer (score 1):

If you want to finish the application in T seconds then you must use a `QTimer::singleShot()` so that when it is triggered then `QCoreApplication::quit()` is invoked:

```py
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(T * 1000, QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit)
```

In the example that you link, it has another objective: to print some information every T seconds and after repeating K times the application is closed, and therefore uses a complicated logic that you do not need.

Considering the above and [the PyQt5 recommendation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code), the solution is:

```py
import sys
import winsound

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(321, 249)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 320, 248))
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.label.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Plays the movie in the Label
        movie = QtGui.QMovie("giphy.gif")
        self.label.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        # Plays the sound with the movie
        winsound.PlaySound("magicwrd.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_LOOP)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(15 * 1000, QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! I tried using the SingleShot as linked before, but I was using it  wrong.

Comment: @Nicholas If my answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, if you do not know how to do it then check the [tour]

Comment: @Nicholas Why does it erase the MRE? You also want to erase much of my answer.

Comment: @Nicholas Do not vandalize my answer since you could be sanctioned, and I will reverse the change.